# Widgets Look ugly after installing AMD/ATI drivers

Tags: 12.10, unity, ati, widgets

I installed video drivers for my ATI card and now (some of) my windows have ugly widgets. Mainly, Firefox looks ugly but natuilus looks find.

Also, my media keyboard buttons stopped working. I can no longer change the volume from my keyboard.

[image: nautilus is fine but Firefox's tab looks like it's from 1999]

Answer (score 0):

do you have "MyUnity" installed?  If so, change the 'themes' tab to 'default' for both 'themes' and 'icons' and see if that helps.